# Used pip install virtualenvwrapper-win and then mkvirtualenv fn on my windows 10 machine. It then says command not found?

Tags: python

```
\Python_work> mkvirtualenv python-course  
mkvirtualenv : The term 'mkvirtualenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,      
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ mkvirtualenv python-course
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mkvirtualenv:String) [], CommandNotFoundException  
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

\Python_work> pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenvwrapper-win in c:\users\acer\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (1.2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\users\acer\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper-win) (20.25.0)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.7 in c:\users\acer\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from virtualenv->virtualenvwrapper-win) (0.3.8)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.12.2 in c:\users\acer\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from virtualenv->virtualenvwrapper-win) (3.13.1)
Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs<5,>=3.9.1 in c:\users\acer\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from virtualenv->virtualenvwrapper-win) (4.1.0)

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 23.3.2
[notice] To update, run: C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip


Python_work> mkvirtualenv python-course  
mkvirtualenv : The term 'mkvirtualenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,      
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ mkvirtualenv python-course
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mkvirtualenv:String) [], CommandNotFoundException  
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```